# SQL - Order By "Custom Preference List"

Tags: mysql, sql

**Scenario**:

I have a column in a MySql table:

my_column - [INT] (Unsigned)

**What I need**:

I need a query to select ONE ENTRY with conditions as follows:

*Given A=n*

```
SELECT FIRST the one with my_column = n

ELSE (my_column = n null result)

SELECT the one with my_column = 0

ELSE

SELECT the one with my_column = whatever

ELSE

Return 0 entries
```

**What I looked into**:

I tried:

`... WHERE`my_column`IN (n,0) ORDER BY`my_column`DESC LIMIT 1`

Which applies for the first two steps, but not for the third one.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your description, just use `case`:

```
order by (case when field = n then 1
               when field = 0 then 2
               else 3
          end)
```

Then, of course, you would add `limit 1`.

Comment: You need to consider also the third condition, so there the case shoud be.... case when field = n then 2 when field = 0 then 1 else 0 end

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO . . . I interpret "FIELD=whatever" as saying that if the first two conditions are not met, then any other value can be returned.

Comment: Thanks both for taking your time. Question Solved. Thanks a lot.